# what is the meaning of using alter session set nls_date_format in plsql developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I often see this code in the company , in a procedure

```
begin
 execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''yyyy-mm-dd''' ;
 .......
```

What is the point of that, or under what conditions do we need to use this statement? because in PLSQL we have already set the time format, so this confuses me , i think it's useless！

Comment: well it sets the date format for that session.  That can include a time component also.  PL/SQL developer settings are for it, not the system.   Not sure I totally understand what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is used as the format model to implicitly cast from date-to-string or string-to-dates.

If you do:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('27-03-2023') FROM DUAL;
```

Then that is effectively the same as:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         '27-03-2023',
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

and if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MM-YYYY` (or an equivalent) then the implicit conversion will work but it the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not equivalent then the query will fail (or give an erroneous result).

Similarly, using:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2023-03-27') FROM DUAL;
```

Then that is effectively the same as:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         DATE '2023-03-27',
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

And it will be formatted according to the current value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

---

> What is the point of that, or under what conditions do we need to use this statement? because in PLSQL we have already set the time format

If you are always use:

```sql
TO_DATE(string_value, format_model)
TO_CHAR(date_value, format_model)
```

And explicitly specify the format model in the second parameter then it is pointless.

If you do not always specify the format model and rely on implicit conversions then it is ensuring that your implicit conversions always use the correct format model. However, implicit conversions are considered to be bad practice and it would be better to always specify the format model and remove the dynamic calls to set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` when you next come to update those procedures and functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

This is setting the default date format for display and (probably more importantly) for input in various commands. It is meant only to alter the default within the scope of the current session, not for all users or as a persistent change for the database. It may be included in a script or procedures because of a specific format requirement when the current value cannot be assumed: setting values like this explicitly to ensure proper operation rather than relying on externally defined defaults is good practice. It is often used for example in situations like point in time recovery operations when the recovery target is a specific timestamp and the default input filter needs to match the format used later in the recovery command.